# Trying to import one js file to another

Tags: javascript, html

I managed to import a function from my main.js to my signin.js, but for some reason, I get this error on my sign in html page `Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')`

and the function for the signin js is not working and I need to import the function of the main.js as the signin js function relys on the main.js function to work.

HTML 1 - signin js

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="../js/main.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="../js/signin.js" type="module"></script>
    <title>Sign in</title>
</head>
<body>

    <main>
    <form class="form-container">
        <input class="email" type="text" placeholder ="Email Address">
        <input class="password" type="password" placeholder ="Password">
        <a href="#" class="sign-in">Sign In</a>
        <a href="../pages/registration.html" class="register">Register</a>
    </form>
     
 </main>
</body>
```

signin.js imported function

```
//import function
import { validate } from "../js/main.js";

let registration = validate();

let signInbtn = document.querySelector(".sign-in");

signInbtn.addEventListener("click", check);

function check(){
    let storedEmail = localStorage.getItem('email');
    let storedPw = localStorage.getItem("password");


    let email = document.querySelector(".email");
    let password = document.querySelector(".password");

    if(email.value == storedEmail && password.value == storedPw){
        alert("You are logged in")
    }
    else{
        alert("Email or Password is incorrect please check and try again.")
    }

    
}
}
```

HTML 2 - main.js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/main.css" />
    <script src="../js/main.js" type="module"></script>
    <title>Register</title>
  </head>
  <body>

<main>
  <div class="heading">
         <h1>User Registration</h1>
    </div>

    <form action="../index.html" class="form-container">
      <ul>
      <li><label for="name">Name</label>
        <input class="name" type="text" name="name" required />
      </li>

      <li><label for="surname">Surname</label>
        <input class="surname" type="text" name="surname" required />
      </li>

      <li><label for="phone">Phone</label>
    <input class="phone" type="text" name="phone" />
      </li>

      <li><label for="email">Email</label>
      <input class="email" type="text" name="email" required /></li>
      
      <li><label for="password">Password</label>
      <input class="password" type="text" name="password" required /></li>
      <button class="reg">Register</button>
</ul>
    </form>
  
</main>

  </body>
</html>
```

main.js

```
let registration = document.querySelector(".reg");

registration.addEventListener("click", validate);

export function validate() {

  //get html elements
  const formEl = {
    id: createId(),
    name: document.querySelector(".name").value,
    surname: document.querySelector(".surname").value,
    phone: document.querySelector(".phone").value,
    email: document.querySelector(".email").value,
    password: document.querySelector(".password").value,
  };

  let name = formEl.name;
  let surname = formEl.surname;
  let email = formEl.email;
  let password = formEl.password;

  if (!name) {
    alert("Please fill in name");
  }

  if (!surname) {
    alert("Please fill in Surname");
  }

  if (!email) {
    alert("Please fill in email");
  }

  if (!password) {
    alert("Please create a password");
  }

  usersArray.push(formEl);
  store();

  return formEl;
}
```

This error I get in the HTML 1 page

[image]

[image]

for some reason, it is preventing the sign-in function from executing. I am doing it this way for practice purposes, I know local storage is not the best method for this, but I am getting used to how local storage works.

Comment: your scripts are in the `head` so they're executed before the elements that you're referencing exist in the DOM. Move them to the bottom of the `body` and you should be fine. (Or at least get past this error - I haven't looked at the rest of your code.)

Comment: I thought the ```type="module"``` has a built-in defer, which means that the script does not need to go to the bottom of the body? unless I am mistaken

Comment: There is no "reg" class in HTML1 yet main.js uses `document.querySelector(".reg");`.

Comment: @Sheldon - apologies, according to MDN you are right. (I'm not familiar with using JS modules directly in HTML, although I'm used to writing them to be bundled with webpack or similar!)